# Local minimum for $c \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
> x^{2}c &x=0 \\ 
> x^{2}(\sin \frac{1}{x}+c) &x \neq 0 
> \end{cases}$$ where $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $c \in \mathbb R$.
>
> (a) Prove that if $c  \ge 1$ then $f$ has a local minimum in $0$ but for any $r>0$ functions $(f)|_{[0,r]}$ and $(f)|_{[-r,0]}$ aren't monotonic.
>
> (b) For which $ c $ minimum local in $0 $ is exact?
>
> (c) Is $ f $ differentiable?

**My try**
(a) If $c \ge 1$ then $\sin \frac{1}{x}+c \ge 0$. So this condition must be truth to that a local minimum in $0$ would be possible. For all other $c$, we would be able to find a value as close to $0$ such that $f \le 0$. However this fact is insufficient to proof this task. At the same time $$f'(x)= \begin{cases} 2xc &x=0 \\ 2x\sin \frac{1}{x}+x^{2}\cos \frac{1}{x}+2xc & x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$ and I don't know how to calculate when $2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}+2xc$ is $\ge/\le 0$ and I do not know another way how to check the monotonicity of this function
Can you help me with this task?

Comment: Your derivative, while technically correct, isn't achieved the right way. The derivative at $x = 0$ isn't gotten by differentiating the $x = 0$ case of the function. (Consider what would happen if for $x = 0$, we had $f(x) = c(x^2 + x)$ instead. This would give the exact same $f$, but would give you a different $f'(0)$).

Comment: @Arthur in $0$ I should
explore differentiability $ f'(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin(1/x) + xc $

Comment: That's right. The derivative at $0$ is dependent on what the function is _around_ $0$ as well as at $0$.

Comment: @Arthur ok, but I still do not know how to do this task